# There is an exception when unlocking excel cells using c#

Tags: c#

I am Trying following code but there is an exception:

> Cannot change part of a merged cell.

The exception was thrown at this line:

```
PortfolioSheet.get_Range("A1",missing).EntireColumn.Locked = false;
```

The full code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ThisApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook ThisWorkBook;

string _stFileName = Server.MapPath("/ExcelTemplate/EFIRM_Facility_Template.xlsm");
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

ThisWorkBook = ThisApplication.Workbooks.Open(_stFileName, missing, missing, 5, missing, missing, missing,
    missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);


Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet PortfolioSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)ThisWorkBook.Sheets[1]; //fill portfoliosheet
//PortfolioSheet.get_Range("A1" + dtDynamicForPortfolio.Rows.Count + "").Locked = false;
/* This line */
PortfolioSheet.get_Range("A1",missing).EntireColumn.Locked = false;
PortfolioSheet.get_Range("B1", "H1"+dtDynamicForPortfolio.Rows.Count).Locked = false;
int iCol = 1;
int iRow = 0;

foreach (DataRow r in dtDynamicForPortfolio.Rows)
{
    iRow++;
    iCol = 0;

    foreach (DataColumn c in dtDynamicForPortfolio.Columns)
    {
        iCol++;

        PortfolioSheet.Cells[iRow + 1, iCol] = Convert.ToString(r[c.ColumnName]);
    //  ThisSheet.get_Range("A1", "C3").Locked = true;
    }
}

PortfolioSheet.get_Range("A1", missing).EntireColumn.Locked = true;
PortfolioSheet.get_Range("B1", "H1").Locked = true;
```

How can I avoid this ?

Comment: [unmerge](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/merge-and-unmerge-cells-HP005251021.aspx)

Comment: If you unmerge the entire worksheet, you propably need a way to make those merged cells back in to the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

You have a merged cell on some row in the excel you are editing. Excel.Interop does not allow you to change entirecolumn/entirerows if you have those on that specific column/row. You need to specify specific range where you do not have a merged cell.

Merged cell is such where you have multiple columns/rows grouped up to act as single cell in excel.